# Specify a maximum and a minimum value [a question on coordination]

Tags: articles, determiners, coordinating-conjunctions

Let's say we are asking the user to specify a maximum and a minimum. What is the correct (and the most natural) way to coordinate the phrase?

- Specify a maximum and a minimum value
- Specify a maximum and minimum value(s)

I have just skimmed through the sections on the coordination of determiners in Cambridge Grammar of the English Language and A comprehensive grammar of the English Language, but I'm still not sure what is right in this particular case.

Comment: Use the singular in this case, with both indefinite articles in place.

Comment: Your first variant is totally acceptable; it uses deletion in an idiomatic way and remains unambiguous.